# What's the difference between 'in the distance' and 'from a distance'?

Tags: difference, prepositional-phrases

Is there any difference in the meaning of these two phrases:
'**in the distance**' and '**from a distance**'?

And the following two sentences sound different?

> He looks good in the distance.
> He looks good from a distance.

Answer (score 4):

The difference is in your starting point; where you measure the distance from.

You use *in the distance* when you start measuring the distance from where you are standing:

> I could see him in the distance, 10km away from me.

You use *from a distance* when you start measuring from the object you are looking at, in this case where 'he' is standing:

> I can see him from a distance - I am 10km away from him.

Answer (score 2):

> I saw a boat in the distance. (The boat was far away from my location.)

*in the distance* is itself almost a "location"  that one sees far away. Where was the boat? It was in the distance.

> I saw a boat from a distance. (I was far away from the boat when I saw it.)

Answer (score 1):

"I saw a boat in the distance." - I think it emphasizes the boat, which is far away.

"I saw a boat from a distance." - It emphasizes the action. I perform this action "SAW" far away from the boat.

Answer (score 0):

1. From a distance (not near)
   e.g. From a distance he ​looks a ​bit like Johnny Depp.
2. In a distance (far away)
   On a ​clear ​day you can ​see the ​temple in the distance.

Reference: [Cambridge Dictionary](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/distance)

Personally, I think "From a distance" refers to something that is not close to you, while "In a distant" suggests that something is far away from you. I can't clearly tell you the difference, but I can feel the distinction.

Comment: So what is the difference between 'not near' or 'not close' and 'far away'?